# How to subclass Pango::Renderer in C++

Tags: c++, pango

I'm trying to subclass the `Pango::Renderer` to draw text on an `osg::Texture2D`, but I cannot find a public constructor (except a copy-constructor) in its header file, neither another method to create a `Pango::Renderer` instance (like a static `create` method the `Layout` class for example provides).

So, how would I:

1. create a `Pango::Renderer` instance
2. subclass `Pango::Renderer`.

I've tried the following code for subclassing:

```
#include <pangomm/renderer.h>

class PangoRendererCanvas: public Pango::Renderer {
    public:
        PangoRendererCanvas() {}
};
```

but that gave the following compilation error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Pango::Renderer::Renderer()’

        PangoRendererCanvas::PangoRendererCanvas() {
                                                                                   ^
```

According to the docs for `Pango::Renderer`, this should be possible:

[Pango::Renderer API documentation](https://developer-old.gnome.org/pangomm/stable/classPango_1_1Renderer.html)

> By subclassing Pango::Renderer and overriding operations such as draw_glyphs and draw_rectangle, renderers for particular font backends and destinations can be created.

I'm using PangoMM 2.46.2.

Comment: *except two copy-constructors* A class can't have two copy constructors.

Comment: @273K Well, you could call it a two-signature copy-constructor, too: `Renderer(const Renderer&) = delete; Renderer& operator=(const Renderer&) = delete;`

Comment: `PangoRendererCanvas::PangoRendererCanvas(PangoText* el, Pango::Context* ctx)` is unrelated to the shown code bit.

Comment: I would look at the file pangomm/renderer.h instead of the manual.

Comment: You should try calling a proper constructor.

Comment: @273K I just checked, the manual was generated directly from the source code, as the code comment states exactly the same.

Comment: @user7860670 I'd like to, but there is none !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just checked, the manual was generated directly from the source code, as the code  comment states exactly the same.

As I suggested, I would look at the header files. The manual is not clear enough. There are protected constructors, they are inherited from `Object`. The first one is what you need to use.

```
protected:
  explicit Renderer(const Glib::ConstructParams& construct_params);
  explicit Renderer(PangoRenderer* castitem);
```

Inherited from

```
protected:
  explicit Object(const Glib::ConstructParams &construct_params);
  explicit Object(GObject *castitem);
```

Comment: Ah, I see. But the constructor of `Glib::ConstructParams` takes a Glib::Class as parameter …

Comment: Found it - `Pango::Renderer_Class`, defined in `/usr/include/pangomm-1.4/pangomm/private/renderer_p.h` - thanks for you help !

Comment: Problem is, this code: `PangoRendererCanvas::PangoRendererCanvas():
 Pango::Renderer(Glib::ConstructParams(renderer_class_.init()))
{}` crashes my application: `(process:323688): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 14:05:33.149: cannot register existing type 'gtkmm__PangoRenderer' (process:323688): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 14:05:33.151: g_object_newv: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
Thread 1 "fgfs" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.`